# I want to display the date on reports as mm/dd/yyyy

Tags: date-preferences

I'd like the dates to display as mm/dd/yyyy instead of Month dd, yyyy.

Answer (score 6):

Go to Administer, Localization, Date Formats at civicrm/admin/setting/date?reset=1 and change the Complete Date to the format you'd like.

I think %m/%E/%Y is what you're looking for.